# Did Bertrand Russell foresee, in 1943, the 21st century’s propensity to assign factuality to whatever information one finds most comfortable?

Tags: truth, bertrand-russell, pragmatism, dewey

I recently read a short paragraph in Russell’s “History of Western Philosophy” which stunned me—it was the shock of recognition—to the extent that I put down the book and stared into space for a good ten minutes.

From Russell’s chapter on John Dewey:

> Dewey's divergence from what has hitherto been regarded as common sense is due to his refusal to admit "facts" into his metaphysic, in the sense in which "facts" are stubborn and cannot be manipulated. In this it may be that common sense is changing, and that his view will not seem contrary to what common sense is becoming.

Was Russell’s 1943 hypothesis about a possible change in the nature of common sense a brilliantly prescient insight? Or was Russell’s biting summing up of Dewey’s pragmatism just another example of the irony (as if common sense could *ever* change) he often uses in this book to demolish a philosophical argument he disagrees with?

To put the question in another way: Might the propensity of many 21st century Americans—perhaps the majority of them—to regard as factual whatever information makes them most comfortable be a popular re-emergence, simplified (and trivialized) over three generations, of the pragmatic theory of truth developed by Pierce, James and Dewey? Or did Russell just get lucky?

Comment: Is the existence of confirmation bias a new thing ?

Comment: I don't see why the suggestive attitude of the last paragraph and the question title is necessary. It adds nothing to an otherwise good question

Comment: While the existence of confirmation bias may not be new, its increasing prevalence is new, and has been remarked upon by many sociologists, for example, Brendon Nyhan and Jason Reifler, in papers dating back to at least 2008.

Comment: Sorry for the snarky last paragraph of my question. A question title of some sort is required; I didn't realize that it was supposed to add something to the question itself.